# What is the origin of these WW1 "official history" maps?

Tags: world-war-one, united-kingdom, sources, maps

I'm looking for a source, preferably the original atlas or set of documents in facsimile, for the following WW1 maps (and their siblings):

[image]

[image]

I've only found these fragments, [reproduced on the Web](http://www.1914-1918.net/bat1.htm) and identified as coming from "British Official History", but can find no information that would lead me to a more complete, printed source.

Where are these maps originally from and who produced them? Are they, and others like them, currently available in print?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Wikipedia page on the British Official History of the Great War.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Great_War)

A lot of the volumes are available as PDFs in various web archives. For example, this map, in the chapter on First Contact with the Enemy is extracted from a volume freely available:

[image]

Comment: Any idea whether these are available in print; perhaps assembled in a volume of just maps?

Comment: The maps are in the relevant books. There is no one collection of maps. The books come in sets, some of which are easier to find than others. Sets typically cost about $500 and there are about 20 different sets. The alternative to buying them is to go to a large library that has them.